# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Seasoned Advice's [fifth moderator election](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/election/5) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Stephie]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/election/5), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6274813928669184/0).

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 12):

Congratulations, Stephie! We're excited to have you join us, and looking forward to working with you.

Also, thanks to Catija and Cindy for entering the race. We'd have loved to have both of y'all as well.

And thank you as well to the 197 voters! It's nice to see how many people out there are interested in the community.